# Regular Expression: Match word and save anything else until space

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to regex for words matching @food_**_ or #food__** in a string, so that I always match @food or #food and any other letters succeeding until a space. This is giving me errors:

```
preg_match_all('/\#/food/i', $unparsed, $parsed);
```

Also, how can I add conditions like matching: Food, FOOD & food ?

Comment: the flag 'i' gives you the case-insensitive option. You've already matching it with flag turned on.

Comment: Since none of the answers explains: The error you got is from the raw `/` slash within the regex. You already use `/` as delimiters on each end of the regex, thus it's an syntax error to use it unescaped within. The backslash here `\#` was unneccessary however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/[#@]food\S*/i', $unparsed, $parsed);
```